# Trying to Open a Text File from Non Default Folder in Android

Tags: android, location, storage, default

I'm saving a file to a non-default spot in Android and am trying to be able to open it to load information from it but cannot find a way to specify the path to the file...

Here is how I am saving the file...

File directory = new File(path + "/Android/data/com.etechtour/save_data/");

```
    directory.mkdirs();

    extStorageDirectory = path.toString() + "/Android/data/com.etechtour/save_data/";

    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pumpItUpGas.txt");
    try
    {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);
        out.write("Record#: " + record + ", Nickname: " + nickname + ", Year: " + year + ", Make: " + make + ", Model: " + model);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    }
```

Now I've successfully saved the file to this location, but when trying to access it I can't figure out ANYTHING that works to set the path to load the file. I've looked around everywhere online and can't seem to find anything that works except using the default save position. Here's how I'm trying to load but am either forceclosing or getting null pointer exceptions

```
try 
{
        String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +  "/Android/data/com.etechtour/save_data/pumpItUpGas.txt";
        InputStream in = openFileInput("pumpItUpGas.txt");
        //FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        //FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(path);
        if (in != null)
        //if (fileReader != null)
        {
            InputStreamReader temp = new InputStreamReader(in);
            //InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(temp);   
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                buf.append(str);
            }
            //fileInput.close();
            in.close();

            return str;

        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the FileOutputStream(file) allows you to successfully save while FileInputStream(file) doesn't allow you to read, using the same file?

Comment: Right, I am saving to the folder "/Android/data/com.etechtour/save_data/" and the file is called pumpItUpGas.txt but when using InputStream you cannot specify the path so I cannot open that same file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FileInputStream` or `FileReader` with your `File` object, just like normal Java I/O.